# Logging users' usernames from an array using Userid discord.js 13v

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a "`ReqUsers`" field in the "`commandInformation`" object, and basically trying to make it check if the `message.author` either has the required permissions and/or roles (if any) or if the `message.author.id` is listed on the "`ReqUsers`". Else, return a message saying that he can't run that command, which works, but one problem, I'm trying to make it say "...only `(list of users that can)` can run this command.", but after 13v came, I never found a way to get users using their id. I've tried `client.users.cache.find(user => user.id == "userid")`, `client.users.cache.get("userid")`, and `message.guild.members.fetch("userid")`, but I never got anything other than "undefined" or "Promise { < pending > }" which of none gave a user.

Here's the code.

```js
/* DisShop Copyrights */

// Main Requirements \\

const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { Secrets, Channels, Guilds, Roles, Permission } = require(`../../config`)


// Important Values \\

const commandInformation = 
{
    CommandName: "check",
    Alias: [],
    ReqPermissions: [],
    ReqRoles: [],
    ReqUsers: ["userid2", "userid2"]
}


// Optional Requirements \\

const db = require("quick.db")

const anyRequiredRoles = commandInformation.ReqRoles.length > 0
const anyRequiredPermissions = commandInformation.ReqPermissions.length > 0
const anyRequiredUsers = commandInformation.ReqUsers.length > 0

const anyRequirements = anyRequiredRoles == false && anyRequiredPermissions == false && anyRequiredUsers == false

// Code \\

module.exports = client => {
    client.on('messageCreate', message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return
        if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(Secrets.PREFIX.toLowerCase())) return

        const command = message.content.toLowerCase()
        const args = command.replace(Secrets.PREFIX.toLowerCase(), '').split(' ')

        if (args[0].toString().toLowerCase() == commandInformation.CommandName || commandInformation.Alias.includes(args[0])) {

            // Permit Check \\

            var Permited_2 = 0

            if (anyRequiredPermissions || anyRequiredRoles) {
                if (anyRequiredPermissions&& !Permited_1 >= 1) {
                    if (commandInformation.ReqPermissions.some(permission => message.member.permissions.has(permission))) Permited_2++;
                }
                if (anyRequiredRoles && Permited_2 <= 0 && !Permited_1 >= 1) {
                    if (commandInformation.ReqRoles.some(role => message.member.roles.cache.has(role))) Permited_2++;
                }
            }
            
            var Permited_1 = 0

            if (anyRequiredUsers) {
                if (commandInformation.ReqUsers.some(userid => message.author.id == userid)) Permited_1++;
                console.log(commandInformation.ReqUsers)
                console.log(commandInformation.ReqUsers.some(userid => message.author.id == userid))
                console.log(Permited_1)
            }

            let allowedUsersList = []
            const allowedUsers = commandInformation.ReqUsers.forEach(userid => allowedUsersList.push(message.guild.members.cache.find(user => user.id == userid)))
            console.log(allowedUsersList, message.guild.members.fetch("735962632619819041"))

            if (!Permited_1 >= 1 && !Permited_2 >= 1) return message.reply(`You're not allowed to use this command, only ${allowedUsersList.join(`, `)} can.`)
            if (!Permited_2 >= 1 && !Permited_1 >= 1 && anyRequiredPermissions || anyRequiredRoles) return message.reply(`Sorry, you don't have the required permissions and/or roles.`)

            // Main Code \\

            message.reply(`Checks out.`)
        }
    })
}
```

Part that isn't working:

```js
let allowedUsersList = []
const allowedUsers = commandInformation.ReqUsers.forEach(userid => allowedUsersList.push(message.guild.members.cache.find(user => user.id == userid)))
console.log(allowedUsersList, message.guild.members.fetch(""))
```

More Info:

```cs
"discord.js": "^13.10.2"
"npm": "8.5.0"
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fetch the members first. The [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method returns a promise so you'll need to resolve it first. You can use `await` for this.

Instead of `forEach` you could also use `map` which creates a new array. And instead of `members.cache.find` you could use `members.cache.get` with the user ID.

You'll also need to make sure that the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent is enabled otherwise you won't be able to fetch the members. You can add `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS` to your intents array.

Check out the working example below:

```js
const commandInformation = {
  CommandName: 'check',
  Alias: [],
  ReqPermissions: [],
  ReqRoles: [],
  ReqUsers: ['userid1', 'userid2'],
};

try {
  await message.guild.members.fetch();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}

const allowedUsersList = commandInformation.ReqUsers.map((user) =>
  message.guild.members.cache.get(user),
);

console.log(allowedUsersList);
```

Another option is to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for every member from that list to be fetched and only log them once all of these promises are resolved:

```js
const commandInformation = {
  CommandName: 'check',
  Alias: [],
  ReqPermissions: [],
  ReqRoles: [],
  ReqUsers: ['userid1', 'userid2'],
};

const promises = commandInformation.ReqUsers.map(
  async (user) => await message.guild.members.fetch(user),
);
const allowedUsersList = await Promise.all(promises);

console.log(allowedUsersList);
```

If you want to get the tags only, you can iterate over the members:

```js
const allowedUsersList = await Promise.all(promises);
const tags = allowedUsersList.map((m) => m.user.tag);

console.log(tags);
```

Comment: ```
Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Hamoodi\Desktop\Discord bots\Voidyy's Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:454:16)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT'
}

Comment: And, there was a LONG pause before it errored and replied, I'd think that's because of the member count

Comment: However, it does work, but the long pause isn't a good thing.

Comment: It sounds like missing `GUILD_MEMBERS` intents to me

Comment: Still, a long delay before the reply, when I was using 12v, it never had a delay, and it was in a large server too.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with another solution, can you check if that works for you?

Comment: It seems to work, but, and sorry for asking too much, but I wanted to get the tag or username xD (tag would be better)

I tried adding ".username" or ".tag" but I'm not sure if any of those worked.

Comment: No worries, I've added that too.

Comment: You're the best, I've never had this kind of help before, keep it up!